# Insert img tag in nested for loop in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to add variable quantity images within nested for loop in asp.net mvc razor view page. My code-

```
foreach (var row in ViewBag.BrandPromoters.Rows)
{    
    string stars = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {                      
        stars +=  "<img src='@(ViewBag.BaseUrl)/star.png' />";               
    }                    
    <div>@stars</div>                    
}
```

But it shows as text in the div tag, not the image.
Any help?

Comment: try <div>Html.raw(stars)</div> ?

Comment: Why not just `<div>for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { <img src="@(ViewBag.BaseUrl)/star.png" /> }</div>`

Comment: @FrebinFrancis, Thanks. It's working. Post it in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `<div>@Html.Raw(stars)</div>` instead of `<div>@stars</div>`

For your information on [HTML Raw()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx)

Hope this helps